# Frames skipped - How do i make a second thread in android studio?

Tags: android

i have got a question about threads in android studio.
I got a really long code in my onCreate method with lots of click listners and textwatchers.
Now i have got this "80 frames skipped" error (in emulator)

ok i know 80 frames are not that much but i wanna avoid to get more frames skipped...i read that the solution is a new thread but somehow when i make a new thread in oncreate and i put my code in it i get "300 frames skipped"?! i think i did everything right i made my thread with new thread new runnable and i of course started it...am i doing somwthing wrong? can someone pls say me how to correctly make a thread and where to place it?
thanks!
 Ok guys here is my code (declarations an definations are not included) in onCreate im just making some stuff like make a phone call and sending sms..those editexts are the names of buttons which the user can edit like he wants and all this stuff is saved in shared preference..i got a second activity for saving the data buti think it doesnt matter right now...i want to put this code in a second thread to not get any frames skipped or at least not much..thanks!

```
call.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrate(78);
                if (!sharedPreferences.getString("nummer", null).isEmpty() && sharedPreferences.getString("nummer", null) != null) {
                    phoneCall(sharedPreferences.getString("nummer", null));
                } else {
                    toasttext("Keine Nummer gefunden!");
                }
            }
        }
);


scharf.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrate(78);
                if (!sharedPreferences.getString("Scharfnummer", "").isEmpty() && sharedPreferences.getString("Scharfnummer", null) != null) {
                    sendSms(sharedPreferences.getString("Scharfnummer", null), sharedPreferences.getString("Scharftext", null));
                    toasttext("Erfolgreich gesendet!");
                } else {
                    toasttext("Keine Daten gefunden!");
                }
            }
        }
);

unscharf.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrate(78);
                if (!sharedPreferences.getString("Unscharfnummer", "").isEmpty() && sharedPreferences.getString("Unscharfnummer", null) != null) {
                    sendSms(sharedPreferences.getString("Unscharfnummer", null), sharedPreferences.getString("Unscharftext", null));
                    toasttext("Erfolgreich gesendet!");
                } else {
                    toasttext("Keine Daten gefunden!");
                }
            }
        }
);

cam1.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrate(78);
                if (!sharedPreferences.getString("cam1", "").isEmpty() && (sharedPreferences.getString("cam1", null) != null)) {
                    openLink(sharedPreferences.getString("cam1", null));
                } else {
                    toasttext("Kein Link gefunden!");
                }
            }
        }
);

cam2.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrate(78);
                if (!sharedPreferences.getString("cam2", "").isEmpty() && sharedPreferences.getString("cam2", null) != null) {
                    openLink(sharedPreferences.getString("cam2", null));
                } else {
                    toasttext("Kein Link gefunden!");
                }
            }
        }
);

cam3.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrate(78);
                if (!sharedPreferences.getString("cam3", "").isEmpty() && sharedPreferences.getString("cam3", null) != null) {
                    openLink(sharedPreferences.getString("cam3", null));
                } else {
                    toasttext("Kein Link gefunden!");
                }
            }
        }
);


editCall.setText(getData("editCall", "Call"));

editCall.addTextChangedListener(
        new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setData("editCall", s.toString());
            }
        }
);

editArm.setText(getData("editArm", "Arm"));
editArm.addTextChangedListener(
        new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setData("editArm", s.toString());
            }
        }
);
editDisarm.setText(getData("editDisarm", "Disarm"));
editDisarm.addTextChangedListener(
        new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setData("editDisarm", s.toString());
            }
        }
);

editCam1.setText(getData("editCam1", "Cam1"));
editCam1.addTextChangedListener(
        new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setData("editCam1", s.toString());
            }
        }
);

editCam2.setText(getData("editCam2", "Cam2"));
editCam2.addTextChangedListener(
        new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setData("editCam2", s.toString());
            }
        }
);

editCam3.setText(getData("editCam3", "Cam1"));
editCam3.addTextChangedListener(
        new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setData("editCam3", s.toString());
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Writing new thread is about Java not Android Studio. However it is still impossible to answer your question whithout seeing your source code and method onCreate particulary.

Comment: Also note that you cannot have two or more threads handling User Interface at once. They will deadlock themselfs. For this, the UI thread is a single thread, and any alteration will stop other threads (and skip the frames)...also, you have weird and non sequitur code (`.getString("nummer", null)`, then a null value is checked for size....

Comment: with this im checking the string not to be empty when it does exist .....if it doesnt exist (=null) nothing happens

Comment: i know the UI is a single thread but i wanna make a second thread for the click listeners and text watchers...when something on UI changes (e.g. a View)i will do it with main thread...so how do i make a thread?

Comment: I think Bonatti is saying that adding listeners and watchers are UI operations and must be done on the UI thread.  I have not tried to do that from a background thread but I don't think it would work.  Have you determined for certain that that's what is causing the frames to be skipped?  Comment out all that code and see what happens.  Adding a listener should be a very fast operation, it could be something else causing it.